# Numpy loading CSV - ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, csv, numpy, neural-network, dataset

I am attempting to train a neural network, however each time I load my dataset I am getting the error:

***ValueError: could not convert string to float***

```
dataset = np.loadtxt('someFile.csv', delimiter=",")

x_train = dataset[:,0:3]
y_train = dataset[:,3]
```

Below is an example of 5 rows from the 3000 in the file.

1,2,12,16

3,4,11,16

2,5,13,16

3,6,13,16

3,4,14,17

The values have been entered from a python script and have been converted to int before they are entered in the CSV.

There are no missing values in the dataset and no strings.

Can anyone shed any light on what could be happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your sample loads fine.  But evidently some other line is not valid.  The trick is to find it.  Unfortunately `loadtxt` doesn't inform of progress or the problem line.

Answer (score 0):

Completely missed the simplest answer.

Instead of converting the list to int into the CSV I changed it to float.